# Showing build queue per slave Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I wanted to ask if you can show build queue that will be executed on a slave. I have many slaves and I can check the global queue but I would like to see a queue dedicated to one slave. Every build fits in regular expression like : "(jobName)_(slaveNumber)".

I could not find any solution from jenkins settings so I wanted to use queue API and get the json that is provided up there then filter the results by this regular expression and display them on one jenkins page. But it turned out that jenkins does not allow to use javascript in description.

Is there a workaround? Or there is some kind of fancy button that will display build queue per slave? I would like to use as simple way as possible so installing "Anything Goes" won't be the solution I want.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried REST api for computers AKA nodes AKA slaves? It shows current load statistic.

```
http://jenkins_site/computer/api/json?depth=1&pretty=true
```

Comment: Thanks but that's actually something different. To get the whole queue I can check: jenkins_site/queue/api/json?pretty=true Then I can filter results by regex. But in the end I am stuck with raw local code. I would like to have something like this:
**Slave1**
_jobsInQueue_
1. Job1
2. Job2
...
etc
And It would be great to have it run on jenkins site.